# Android custom dialog layout error

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I am trying to create my own dialog in app. When I use `layout_weight` in my xml, I got `ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid` in my logcat, however when I am using fixed `layout_width` or `layout_height` everything seems to be fine. Could anyone tell me, where did I go wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_spades"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/orange"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_hearts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_clubs"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/orange"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_diamonds"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/orange"/>

    </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_figures"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton_ace"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@color/orange"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton_king"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@color/orange"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton_queen"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@color/orange"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton_jack"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@color/orange"/>

        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one without giving any height width:

```
        Dialog  dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_friend_data);

        /*******************dialog features*********************/
        final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        window.setLayout(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should remove height and width from all the xml elements?

Comment: i don't know what you have done in your layout. If your dialog is streching and dialog is not showing perfectly then you can use Window with dialog. It will automatically fit to every screen.

Comment: If I look at preview in Android Studio, then layout looks ok. But when I try to load it in app, the height is very small, and no `ImageButtons` are visible. I tried Your solution, but it didn't worked

Comment: I tried with `window.setLayout(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` And it worked :) Thank You